# the application could not be installed: install_failed_bad_permission_group in linux ubuntu

Tags: java, android, linux

### [i am trying to run the android project but while launching the apk in device it shows the application could not be installed: install_failed_bad_permission_group. please help me to resolve this issue. i am using linux ubuntu laptop , i think it is because of some permission issue but i have give the Android studio read and write permission but still i am getting this.i have already tried with adding this line in '''android.injected.testOnly=false''' in gradel.properties][1] Manifest code                                                                  -->          -->  -->                  -->                                                                                                               -->                                      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/grRAV.png

Comment: can u show us AndroidManifest too

Comment: added the manifest

Comment: umm i cant even click the link 
anyway tell u basics like check error in manifist if there is none got to file the invalid crahes and then run and also check target sdk and your device on which u wanna install thats important and download sdk too which is suitable

Comment: tried all these things still getting the application could not be installed: install_failed _bad_ permission_group

Comment: minSdkVersion 23
targetSdkVersion 31

Comment: make target version 32 your device is 32 not 31 and change the other module targetversion to 32

Comment: after making target version 32 your device is 32 not 31 and change the other module targetversion to 32 . still i am getting same error The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_BAD_PERMISSION_GROUP